# Mac Mojave Swap File

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, swap-file

I have a question and I'm not sure if what I'm thinking is possible to do.

I have a 2015 iMac 17 with

- One 4 GHz Intel Core I7
- 64 GB 1867 MHz DDR3 Ram
- AMD Radeon R9 M395 2048 MB
- 2TB Hitachi Hard drive
- 128GB apple SSD

in a fusion configuration running OSx Mojave.
I wonder if I should replace the hard drive with a 2TB SSD and configure it and the Apple SSDs as separate drives?

I was also wondering if I can use the 128GB Apple SSD as a memory file overflow (swap file) location. It's fast like memory, but it's really too small for any computing space I can use in my photography business.

Does anyone know if I can do this and if so: how would I move the swap file and point the OSX to it?

Comment: I'd suggest breaking this Question into two questions : Can the HD be upgraded, and how to break the Fusion configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ask Apple if the new storage device is supported.  In 2011, I brought an iMac and big HD to Apple to have it swapped in, and was told it wasn't supported.  Brought it home and tried to change it myself, and what do you know, a big blinking "No disk found" icon appeared.  It might be doable, but I was stymied at the time.  Incidentally, I broke the monitor cable while doing it and caused a lot of trouble for myself.

I don't know if the SSD will work after breaking the Fusion configuration.  Using it as swap file space might be possible, but the Fusion device is designed as a cache for the whole drive, so the whole experience will only be as fast as the HD itself can manage.

Comment: Thank you for the response, first I'm sorry to hear about your monitor cable. Regarding a new configuration, Apple tech and OWC tech stated the SSD I'm using will work in my 2015. In addition the 128BG Apple SSD can be configured as a stand alone HD. My grey area is can the OSx swap file be moved to the 128GB Apples SSD and OS instruction be pointed to it. This would give me 128GB memory swap space on top of my 64GB memory.

Comment: Not certain.  With a cursory web search, the results I see are for older versions of MacOS.  I suggest trying the swap move before committing yourself to the hardware change.